# In a given C# Windows Forms application/WPF, where are user settings usually stored?

Tags: c#, appsettings, application-settings

I was thinking either:

1. An Appconfig file
2. A generic .XML file and have the program load values at launch.

What is the best way to do this? A website with a best user tutorial perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The .NET Framework 2.0 allows you to
>   create and access values that are
>   persisted between application
>   execution sessions. These values are
>   called settings. Settings can
>   represent user preferences, or
>   valuable information the application
>   needs to use. For example, you might
>   create a series of settings that store
>   user preferences for the color scheme
>   of an application. Or you might store
>   the connection string that specifies a
>   database that your application uses.
>   Settings allow you to both persist
>   information that is critical to the
>   application outside of the code, and
>   to create profiles that store the
>   preferences of individual users.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on the persistence model for the settings:

- are settings per-user based or machine-wide?
- are settings application specific or can/do they need to be used/discovered by other applications as well?
- are settings default values known at design time or are they generated at install time?
- are settings local to particular machine or can/will they be roamed?

The standard [.NET settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx) support local per-user settings (when the user runs as a regular user) and local machine-wide settings (when the user runs as administrator), both with build-time machine-wide default values and for application-use only. This addresses the majority of scenarios. There is some advanced functionality there which allows to use the .NET `Configuration` classes with configuration files in different locations, which can allow for roamable and third-party discoverable settings as well; however, there is no Visual Studio tooling support for such scenarios.